# I'm looking for a city where to go for the next 6 months in Argentina (on the sea)

Tags: destinations, cities, argentina

My criteria are:

- full of life / young people (I don't want a dead city)
- no traffic, no chaos (I hate to drive, I love to bike)
- on the sea (good quality, where I can go easily to swim)
- low crime rate / pollution

In other terms I'm looking for a cozy human-size city, but with many opportunities

Comment: I think that's an interesting question, but I had to vote to close it, since immo it is not travel-related.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I've changed my question

Comment: Since the question is altered and is now looking for a short-term stay, I think it is related to travel and voted to reopen.

Comment: @Patrick - "many opportunities" for what?  It's almost become acceptable as a question, perhaps if you could reword it as per our [faq], we could then reopen it and get you some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mar del Plata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar_del_Plata) might be only city satisfying your criteria. The rest are either not very good for swimming or only have life in the summer.
If you want cities not by the sea but near lakes or rivers, you should consider Mendoza, Bariloche, Rosario and Villa Carlos Paz.